# No data being returned from API

Tags: java, android

Im having difficulties with my app. When i select the refresh button, no data comes through from the server. I know i have missed something critical here but just can't seem to find where i have gone wrong.

Hope you guys can help.

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

public ForecastFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forcastfragment, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute();
        return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    String[] data = {
            "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
            "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/45",
            "Weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
            "Thurs - Rainy - 64/51",
            "Fri - Foggy - 70/46",
            "Sat - WHAT - 76/68"
    };

    List<String> weekForcast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

    mForecastAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForcast);

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {


    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
        Date date = new Date(time * 1000);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
        return format.format(date).toString();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */
    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException {

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DATETIME = "dt";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".
            long dateTime = dayForecast.getLong(OWM_DATETIME);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
        }

        return resultStrs;
    }

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        if(params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int numDays = 7;

        try {

            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Christchurch,nz";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());


            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            //Read the input stream into String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                //Nothing to do
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line = "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                forecastJsonStr = null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error", e);
            //If the placeholder doesn't get the weather data there is no point parsing it
            forecastJsonStr = null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlacementHolderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doInBackground();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if(result != null) {
            mForecastAdapter.clear();
            for (String dayForecasterStr : result) {
                mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecasterStr);
            }
            //New Data is back from the server! :)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The problems with this question are 1) Too Much Code, and 2) you have provided zero supporting evidence.  I'd like to see logcat logs / stacktraces, server-side logs, **detailed** descriptions of what happens, etcetera.

Comment: 1 interesting thing, using `param[0]` at `appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])`, but you are not sending any params at `execute()`this could be NPE!? +++ did you add internet permission? otherwise you have to provide more details, logs ...